# Type casting the character pointer

Tags: c, pointers, typecasting-operator

I am from Java back ground.I am learning C in which i gone through a code snippet for type conversion from int to char.

```
int a=5;
int *p;
p=&a;
char *a0;
a0=(char* )p;
```

My question is that , why we use (char *)p instead of (char)p.

We are only casting the 4 byte memory(Integer) to 1 byte(Character) and not the value related to it

Comment: p is an pointer value of integer a

Comment: No, you are casting the `n bytes` of `a` address pointed by `p` to `a0` char pointer that has the same width

Comment: types must match.

Comment: There exists no reason why you would ever want to cast a `int*` to a `char*`. This would cause all manner of signedness bugs. Perhaps you meant to use `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider pointers as variable that contains addresses. Their sole purpose is to show you where to look in the memory.

so consider this:

```
int a = 65;
void* addr = &a;
```

now the 'addr' contains the address of the the memory where 'a' is located
what you do with it is up to you.

here I decided to "see" that part of the memory as an ASCII character that you could print to display the character 'A'

```
char* car_A = (char*)addr;
putchar(*car_A); // print: A (ASCII code for 'A' is 65)
```

if instead you decide to do what you suggested:

```
char* a0 = (char)addr;
```

- The left part of the assignment `(char)addr` will cast a pointer 'addr' (likely to be 4 or 8 bytes) to a char (1 byte)
- The right part of the assignment, the truncated address, will be assigned as the address of the pointer 'a0'

If you don't see why it doesn't make sense let me clarify with a concrete example

Say the address of **'a'** is **0x002F4A0E** (assuming pointers are stored on 4 bytes) then

- **'*addr'** is equal to **65**
- **'addr'** is equal to **0x002F4A0E**

When casting it like so `(char)addr` this become equal to **0x0E**.
So the line

```
char* a0 = (char)addr;
```

become

```
char* a0 = 0x0E
```

So 'a0' will end up pointing to the address **0x0000000E** and we don't know what is in this location.

I hope this clarify your problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `p` is not necessarily 4 bytes since it's architecture-dependent. Second, `p` is a pointer to an integer, `a0` is a *pointer* to a character, not a character. You're taking a pointer pointing to an integer and casting it to a pointer to a character. There are few good reasons to do this. You could also cast the value to a character, but I can't imagine any reason for doing this either.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers do not provide information whether they point to a single object of first object of an array.

Consider

```
int *p;
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int x = 1;

p = a;
p = &x;
```

So having a value in the pointer `p` you can not say whether the value is the address of the first element of the array `a` or it is the address of the single object `x`.

It is your responsibility to interpret the address correctly.

In this expression-statement

```
a0=(char* )p;
```

the address of the extent of memory pointed to by the pointer `p` and occupied by an object of the type `int` (it is unknown whether it is a single object or the first object of an array) is interpreted as an address of an extent of memory occupied by an object of the type `char`.  Whether it is a single object of the type `char` or the first object of a character array with the size equal to `sizeof( int )` depends on your intention that is how you are going to deal with the pointer.